# Is it not the same to initialise Firebase Hosting from Console and from firebase-tools CLI?

Tags: firebase-hosting

I am trying to setup Firebase [reserved URLS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls) (/__/*) on an existing project and for that, I need to setup Firebase Hosting. So I initialise Firebase Hosting from `firebase-tools` command from the root of my project (using `firebase init hosting` OR `firebase init` and then select `hosting` in the options). But I do not get the reserved URLs option anywhere (any [script tags I add](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls#add_scripts_for_reserved_urls) give me 404 in network tabs). Not that FB Hosting is not initialised because I AM able to use FB Hosting, though. I can deploy and it gives me a firebase URL for my app).

Now, if I go back to my project in Firebase Console > Hosting, it still gives me a link to "Get Started" (shouldn't I not get this since I already initialised FB hosting via CLI?). And if I click this, and proceed with setup and THEN add my script tags, then reserved URLs works fine. I even checked and it has the project name via CLI (`firebase use`) and on the Firebase Console.

I've been going through the docs but I couldn't find anything. There aren't a lot of content out there that address reserved URLs much. Hoping you guys can help out.

Answer (score 1):

The hosting reserved urls (like `/__/firebase/init.js`) are served automatically for you by Firebase Hosting when running your website on both a shared domain `your-id`.web.app/`your-id`.firebaseapp.com, or a [custom domain that you've connected](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).

In order to setup a Hosting shared domain, you either have to run `firebase init`, then `firebase deploy` (Init alone won't enable hosting - you need the deploy to push the configuration to the firebase servers), or set it up though the console.

When [running locally](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying), make sure you're using `firebase serve --only hosting` to get access to them.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work for me. I did `firebase init hosting`, and assumed reserved urls would be setup with this. But when i try to reference `/__/`, I'd get not-found-errors. What worked for me was that I had to go back to FB console and re-init hosting for project  (even tho I had already done a `firebase init hosting` on same project earlier thru VS Code).